# HTML File tag: difference between .files[0] and .value

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I'm writing an AJAX file uploader, and I ran into this issue:
I need to append the file to a FormData, but some browsers support the files attribute of the file tag (defined in html5), and others only support value; so I wrote this:

```
 d.append('mFile',pfile);
```

where pfile is either files[0] or value, depending on what the browser supports.

Only problem: value never works, on any browser.

How can I fix it?

Note: I can't use JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`.files` is a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) and `.files[0]` is a File (or undefined if the list is empty).
`.value` is merely a string (usually an obfuscated file name).
To upload a file with FormData you have to pass a File(or Blob) to it. Passing `.value` will just post the file name.
If the browser supports FormData then it will more than likely support FileList, so there is no reason to pass `.value` to FormData.

Comment: thanks, but how do I get the blob from .value? not all browsers seem to support FileList

Comment: Is there a browser that supports FormData that doesn't support FileList ?

Comment: well... I used a polyfill to get FormData to work in IE9-, but that's not the point, .value doesn't work in firefox nightly either

Comment: @dosse91214 `.value` wont ever work (well maybe except in very old IE with ActiveX). Without Html5 FileApi you can't upload a file selected from a file input via ajax. Your best option would be to simulate it with an iframe or something.

Comment: @dosse91214 are you talking about a specific plugin because jQuery doesn't do anything with FromData.

Comment: the form plugin, i've used it about a year ago for another site